# Password Protecting Folders in OS X?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, password, third-party

What methods exist (either inbuilt or via third party) to password protect (encrypt) folders within OS X ?

Comment: If you search for "password protected folder" on this site, you will find several solutions :-)

Comment: @patrix Ah I searched for password protect, should have entered the whole search term.

Comment: No worries, your question now serves as an additional entry point for future visitors searching the same thing.